# JSON Array Parsing In Android method

Tags: android, arrays, json

I am trying to parse a JSON Array But I Dont know how to parse such Array.
Please explain the concept when you write the code

```
{
  "snappedPoints": [
    {
      "location": {
        "latitude": -35.2784167,
        "longitude": 149.1294692
      },
      "originalIndex": 0,
      "placeId": "ChIJoR7CemhNFmsRQB9QbW7qABM"
    },
    {
      "location": {
        "latitude": -35.280321693840129,
        "longitude": 149.12908274880189
      },
      "originalIndex": 1,
      "placeId": "ChIJiy6YT2hNFmsRkHZAbW7qABM"
    },
    {
      "location": {
        "latitude": -35.280960897210818,
        "longitude": 149.1293250692261
      },
      "originalIndex": 2,
      "placeId": "ChIJW9R7smlNFmsRMH1AbW7qABM"
    },
    {
      "location": {
        "latitude": -35.28142839817933,
        "longitude": 149.1298619971291
      },
      "originalIndex": 3,
      "placeId": "ChIJy8c0r2lNFmsRQEZUbW7qABM"
    },
    {
      "location": {
        "latitude": -35.28193988170618,
        "longitude": 149.13001013387623
      },
      "originalIndex": 4,
      "placeId": "ChIJ58xCoGlNFmsRUEZUbW7qABM"
    },
    {
      "location": {
        "latitude": -35.282819705480151,
        "longitude": 149.1295597114644
      },
      "originalIndex": 5,
      "placeId": "ChIJabjuhGlNFmsREIxAbW7qABM"
    },
    {
      "location": {
        "latitude": -35.283139388422363,
        "longitude": 149.12895618087012
      },
      "originalIndex": 6,
      "placeId": "ChIJ1Wi6I2pNFmsRQL9GbW7qABM"
    },
    {
      "location": {
        "latitude": -35.284728724835304,
        "longitude": 149.12835061713685
      },
      "originalIndex": 7,
      "placeId": "ChIJW5JAZmpNFmsRegG0-Jc80sM"
    }
  ]
}
```

can someone please write the code for this one and explain it?

Thanks in advance

I Tried this one for testing whether it fetch records or not?

```
 JSONArray array = null;
        try {
           array = new JSONArray("snappedPoints");
            for(int i =0; i<= array.length();i++) {
                JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                String Location = (String) object.get("latitude");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, Location, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("============" ,Location );
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: What you need from there? Every single object? You should show part of your code so far... First of all: "snapedPoints" is a JSONArray and, for example, "location" is a JSONObject. JSONArrays can be count and have an array for a "for" statement.

Comment: Questions containing "code-requests" will be downvoted all day long. Please show your attempts at solving the problem.

Comment: I need Latitude and Longitude Only

Comment: First use google search to get tutorial on json parsing....start with simple json object...then try it on your project..after doing all this you get stuck somewhere then post question here

Comment: Google "how to parse json array android", there are dozens of code examples... if you need help here, post your code so far to see how you try to solved.

Comment: I know how to parse a json object But I am having problem with JSON Array And I am Confused with the concept

Comment: I have posted my code please have a look

Comment: It's ok parsing JSONs, when you start is too confusing, because exist too many ways to write a correct JSON structure that represent the same thing.

Comment: Yes I was confused in JSON Arrays and Parsing JSON in Retrofit via GSON.. I also dont know how to parse arrays in GSON but I can parse simple Objects in GSON

Comment: You use retrofit and Gson, let me edit my answer

Comment: Ok Bro And Thanks For your support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok first i gonna writte the code in sample JSON library from Java.

```
String jsonString = "here your json";

JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONArray snappedPoints = json.getJSONArray("snappedPoints");

for (int i = 0; i < snappedPoints.lenght(); i++){
    JSONObject location = snappedPoints.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("location");

    double latitude = location.getDouble("latitude");
    double longitude = location.getDouble("longitude");
}
```

Second i recomend you to use some library like, Jackson, Gson, etc.., to a easies way to convert json into POJOs.

***Edit:***

**Using RetroFit and Gson:**

Frist we declare some simple pojos:

```
    public class SnappedPoint {
        private Location location;
        private int originalIndex;
        private String placeId;

        public Location getLocation() {
            return location;
        }
        public void setLocation(Location location) {
            this.location = location;
        }
        public int getOriginalIndex() {
            return originalIndex;
        }
        public void setOriginalIndex(int originalIndex) {
            this.originalIndex = originalIndex;
        }
        public String getPlaceId() {
            return placeId;
        }
        public void setPlaceId(String placeId) {
            this.placeId = placeId;
        }

    }


    public class Location {
        private double latitude;
        private double longitude;

        public double getLatitude() {
            return latitude;
        }

        public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
            this.latitude = latitude;
        }

        public double getLongitude() {
            return longitude;
        }

        public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
            this.longitude = longitude;
        }
    }
```

After that into your RetroFit Interface declaration you put the next callback:

```
CallBack< HashMap<String, ArrayList<SnappedPoint>> >
```

You should get a`HashMap<String, ArrayList<SnappedPoint>> response`
to get your location info you only have to:

```
ArrayList<SnappedPoint> snappedPoints = response.get("snappedPoints");
for (SnappedPoint snappedPoint : snappedPoints){
    double latitude = snappedPoint.getLocation().getLatitude();
    double longitude = snappedPoint.getLocation().getLongitude();
}
```